# Find substrings in PyMongo

Tags: python, regex, mongodb, pymongo

I wanted to find sub-strings within a field in MongoDB using PyMongo.

The following query works fine and is what I require:

```
db.collection.find({ "Animal": /cat|Dog/i})
```

However, if I try passing the value `/cat|Dog/i` as a string in Python, it doesn't work.

Is there a way to replicate the query in **PyMongo**?

Note: `/cat|Dog/i` is value of field from another collection. It is in the form 'cat Dog'. Basically, I want to match substrings in one field with substrings in another.

Comment: There seems to be no solution

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to compile your regular expression pattern using [`re.compile()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#re.compile) function into a regular expression object.

```
import re

pat = re.compile(r'cat|Dog', re.I)
db.collection.find({ "Animal": {'$regex': pat}})
```