# Pattern Regex in $in in MongoDB

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I am trying to use regex in $in command in MongoDB. However it allows only pattern regex as per the documentation.

When I try using the pattern like this with string list, it fails

```
collection.find({"categories": { "$in": ["/^item1$/i","/^item2$/i","/^item3$/i"] } },{"_id":0}).count()
```

However when I try with this, it works

```
collection.find({"categories": { "$in": [/^item1$/i,/^item2$/i,/^item3$/i] } }).count()
```

Why is this? I am using PyMongo and need to pass a list of string. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

With PyMongo, you will need to create a list of regular expression object by compiling each pattern each object using [`re.compile()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#re.compile) as mentioned [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33919830/find-substrings-in-pymongo) But that will be very inefficient.

Instead, you should write you regex using a character classes. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/tKCLkd/1)

```
import re

pat = re.compile(r'^item[1-3]$')
collection.find({'categories': pat})
```